# Checking output from qsub : Sungrid cluster

Tags: qsub, sungridengine

is there way to check the output of the submitted job. The output files are written with quite big delay, so I want to be able to see if they are anything wrong going on.

I saw for `PBS` there was option `-k oe` to directly write the `qsub` output to file in home directory but could not find similar solution for my case.

Comment: Is this Torque or SGE?  The `-k` option is specific to Torque, but question is tagged sge.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I find on Torque it would seem like this is not doable without configuring server:

[Check real time output after qsub a job on cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29701648/check-real-time-output-after-qsub-a-job-on-cluster)

[PBS, refresh stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10527061/pbs-refresh-stdout)

You may want to consider writing output to separate file from within the program and `flush` stdout accordingly.